# Two way communication socket programming

Tags: android, sockets, bidirectional

I want to build a two way communication  app between two android devices connected on the same network, where one will be treated as server and other will be a client.

[Link to description](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/303737681).

Comment: Well go ahead. Why are you telling us? You dont need permission.

Comment: i just wrote my aim, to describe the problem. the codes in the link are nor working efficiently. so asking for some changes.